# Worried about spiders repeatedly hitting high-demand page

Tags: web-crawler

Due to some rather bizarre architectural considerations I've had to set up something that really ought to run as a console application as a web page. It does the job of writing a large variety of text files and xml feeds from our site data for various other services to pick up so obviously it takes a little while to run and is pretty processor intensive.

However, before I deploy it I'm rather worried that it might get hit repeatedly by spiders and the like. It's fine for the data to be re-written but continual hits on this page are going to trigger performance issues for obvious reasons.

Is this something I ought to worry about? Or in reality is spider traffic unlikely to be intensive enough to cause problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can tell the big ones not to spider you; [www.robotstxt.org](http://www.robotstxt.org/).

You could also implement some form of authentication/ip address criteria that would prevent it from running.

Answer (score 1):

You might be surprised how many spiders there are out there.

You should use `robots.txt` to exclude them.

If you worry that spiders might ignore `robots.txt` (and some inevitably will), how about requiring a POST rather than a GET to trigger the script?  That should exclude all spiders.

Answer (score 0):

You should require authentication for the page.

Even if you exclude it in `robots.txt`, there's no guarantee that spiders will respect that.  If it's an expensive page that might impact site availability, stick it behind an authentication gateway.